# Using PHP's CURL to store API's JSON to variable

Tags: php, rest, curl

I'm trying to store data exposed with the following URL in a PHP variable ($curl_response) for further manipulation, but my current code is not executing properly. I've copied/pasted the data exposed in the following URL into the body of an HTML file and have tried running the below script on that HTML file, and CURL works properly. I'm guessing the issue then has to do with getting a response correctly from this particular site. Perhaps there is a CURL option I'm overlooking.

http://tdm.prod.obanyc.com/api/pullouts/agency/MTABC/list

Thoughts?

```
<?php 

$ch = curl_init("http://tdm.prod.obanyc.com/api/pullouts/agency/MTABC/list");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($ch);

if ($curl_response === false) {
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' . var_export($info));
}
else echo $curl_response ;

curl_close($ch);

?>
```

The debugging output is:

array ( 'url' => '', 'content_type' => NULL, 'http_code' => 0, 'header_size' => 0, 'request_size' => 0, 'filetime' => -1, 'ssl_verify_result' => 0, 'redirect_count' => 0, 'total_time' => 63.145232, 'namelookup_time' => 0.006015, 'connect_time' => 0, 'pretransfer_time' => 0, 'size_upload' => 0, 'size_download' => 0, 'speed_download' => 0, 'speed_upload' => 0, 'download_content_length' => -1, 'upload_content_length' => -1, 'starttransfer_time' => 0, 'redirect_time' => 0, 'certinfo' => array ( ), 'primary_ip' => '10.137.36.11', 'primary_port' => 80, 'local_ip' => '', 'local_port' => 0, 'redirect_url' => '', )error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info:

Comment: Please, don't just say `not executing properly` and talk about "the issue". Show the result, the desired result, why that surprises you, your debugging etc.

Answer (score 0):

Is your else statement in the question the same way it is in the code? If yes, then I would start by fixing the else statement

Change

```
else $curl_response ;
```

to

```
else
{
   $curl_response; // You might want to echo  $curl_response or store it or do something with it. In it's current state it just does nothing.
}
```

Comment: it was correct in the code -- when i posted it on this forum, i accidentally took it out. That's not the problem... I revised the above code accordingly.

Comment: I was informed that the IP address of the site is blocked for servers not in-network. That resolves the no response error and null value of the variable upon CURL execution.

Thanks all --

Answer (score 0):

I was informed that the IP address of the site is blocked for servers not in-network. That resolves the no response error and null value of the variable upon CURL execution.

Thanks all